# YACC-generated parser gives different outputs for same input repeated

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I want to check a string, if it matches the grammar `a^nb^n` using YACC and LEX. Here are my LEX and YACC files in same order:

Lex file:

```
  %{
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <y.tab.h>
  %}

  %%
   a {return A;}
   b {return B;}
   . {return yytext[0];}
   \n {return NL;}
  %%
   int yywrap(void) {
      return 1;
   }
```

YACC file:

```
  %{
   #include <stdio.h>
   yyerror()
  {
    printf("Rejected\n");
   }    
  %}

   %token A B NL
   %start T

   %%

   T : S NL {printf("accepted\n");}
     ;
   S : A S B
     | A B
     ;

  %%

  main()
  {
    yyparse();
  }
```

The problem is the output:

input string:   aabb

output:  Accepted

input string:   aabb

output:  Rejected

When the same input or any input that is suppose to be accepted answer is rejected when entered second time. I learned that YACC has a stack that it uses when it parses the string. But i couldn't find any document regarding that. Please help.

Comment: Try putting the main function in the block where you have written "#include..."

Comment: No, it didn't work. Still it rejects the second time.

Comment: Then. sorry @Midhun, I am not sure what might be the cause for varying outputs.

Comment: Have you recompiled the code after making changes? If not do it. If you already did, then try including yywrap() function in your lex file.

Comment: I have made the change, it is updated above. But still error persists.

Comment: Try including yywrap() in yacc file instead of lex file. I saw it in this link. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/ie_prog_4lex_yacc.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `yacc` rule `T` is non-recursive, meaning that it only matches **one** line.  The following modification will watch any number of lines (including none).

```
T : T S NL
  | /* empty */
  ;
```

Resulting in consecutive lines being accepted.

```
$ printf 'aabb\naabb\n' | ./a.out
accepted
accepted
```

Comment: The OP should note, however, that the return value of `yyparse()` will indicate only whether the *overall* parse is successful; it says nothing about how many input lines were successfully parsed before the first parse failure or end of input.

Comment: `|/* empty */` i  guess this represents the `epsilon` that we use to represent null or empty production in Theoretical grammar.

Comment: @Midhun Note that it is not a special `yacc` syntax, rather a "This page is intentionally left blank." style comment.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your result by running your parser repeatedly, but I *can* reproduce it by feeding the parser multiple strings in the same run.  It is essential to understand the difference: one execution of `yyparse()` is one run, and it will attempt to parse the entire input, up to the point where the lexer signals end-of-file.  @kdhp's answer explains why your parser does not accept multiple strings in the same run, and presents a way to get the result you seem to want.

---

An alternative is to genuinely perform multiple runs, which you can do by adjusting your parser and lexer.  The lexer would need to report end-of-input when it sees a newline, and the parser then wouldn't need to account for newlines at all.

Moreover, the lexer needed in either case is so simple that generating it with `lex` (or `flex`) is overkill; it is much simpler to write a suitable `yylex()` directly.  Furthermore, by writing your own you can more conveniently provide for differentiating in `main()` between end-of-line and end-of-input.  A lexer supporting all that could appear in the grammar file, ahead of `main()`:

```
int end_of_input = 0;

int yylex(void) {
    int c = getc();  /* no buffering inside the lexer */

    if (c < 0) {
        end_of_input = 1;
    }
    return ((c == '\n') ? 0 : c);
}
```

For simplicity, that assumes the parser uses literal tokens, which there is no particular reason for it not to do in this case.  Moreover, the only rule it needs is this variant on your original rule for non-terminal `S` (which is now the start symbol):

```
S : 'a' S 'b'
  | 'a' 'b'
  ;
```

With that lexer and that rule, each run of `yyparse()` will parse up to one line (but may stop on a parse error before end-of-line), and will return `0` if and only if the whole line is successfully parsed.  You then run it in a loop:

```
int main(void)
{
    do {
        if (yyparse() == 0)) {
            puts("accepted");
        } // else yyerror() already printed "rejected"
    } while (!end_of_input);
}
```

As a final note, do recognize that if there is a parse error somewhere in the middle of a line of input, the above does not consume the rest of that line (and neither does your version).  If after an error you want to continue parsing on the next line either in `main()` or via an error rule in the parser.  That can certainly be done; I leave it as an exercise.